# Is it possible to keep all the DSC configurations in Version Control and make Azure Automation fetch it from there automatically?

Tags: automation, azure

The Azure Automation DSC seems to know to integrate with GitHub, but it seems to expect only runbooks there. At least, this is what I understand from the following UI screen:
[image]

I have just started to learn DSC and have no runbooks. So far I only used DSC configurations, no runbooks.

So, is it only possible for runbooks? Does it mean that nobody works with just DSC configurations?

**P.S.** Knowing that DSC stands for Desired State **Configuration** I find the term DSC **configurations** a bit funny.

Answer (score 2):

The article "[Continuous Deployment to Azure Automation DSC](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/automagically/2017/04/11/continous-deployment-to-azure-automation-dsc/)", or series of articles, walks through setting up a CI/CD pipeline for DSC using VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services).  Building a VSTS account in Azure is free and it provides some number of build minutes for free as well.

Basically, rather than setting up a runbook, you can configure a CI/CD pipeline using build services in VSTS to perform whatever orchestration activities you require for DSC and VSTS enables you to save your code in their source control management system.

Comment: Links are subject to break, summarize what you find interesting in your answer and provide the link for further information if needed. I suggest you read [answer] for more information on what we expect (greetings, etc are not needed in posts)